# When I change the value of a variable, why does it not affect the array I put it in?

Tags: python

I tried several different methods none work, I was trying to get the values to change on the fly so I can change the HSV values live to adjust for noise and inaccuracies. The values change fine but it doesn't update the color mask thresholds, I really dont know what else to try, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv


def change_hueL(value1L):
    global hueL
    hueL = value1L
    print("huel: ", hueL)


def change_satL(value2L):
    global satL
    satL = value2L
    print("satL:", satL)


def change_valL(value3L):
    global valL
    valL = value3L
    print("valL: ", valL)


def change_hueU(value1U):
    global hueU
    hueU = value1U
    print("hueU: ", hueU)


def change_satU(value2U):
    global satU
    satU = value2U
    print("satU: ", satU)


def change_valU(value3U):
    global valU
    valU = value3U
    print("valU: ", valU)


hueL = 50
satL = 50
valL = 150
hueU = 180
satU = 255
valU = 255

cv.namedWindow('panel')
cv.createTrackbar('hue lower', 'panel', hueL, 255, change_hueL)
cv.createTrackbar('sat lower', 'panel', satL, 255, change_satL)
cv.createTrackbar('val lower', 'panel', valL, 255, change_valL)
cv.createTrackbar('hue upper', 'panel', hueU, 255, change_hueU)
cv.createTrackbar('sat upper', 'panel', satU, 255, change_satU)
cv.createTrackbar('val upper', 'panel', valU, 255, change_valU)

lower = np.array([hueL, satL, valL])
upper = np.array([hueU, satU, valU])

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while (True):

    # Capture frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:

        color = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv.inRange(color, lower, upper)

        cv.imshow("raw", frame)
        cv.imshow("msk", mask)

        k = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: Try putting the two lines of code `lower = np.array([hueL, satL, valL])` and `upper = np.array([hueU, satU, valU])` between `color = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` and `mask = cv.inRange(color, lower, upper)`.

Comment: yes, that worked! If you dont mind, could you please explain why that works?

Comment: The assignment `lower = np.array([hueL, satL, valL])` creates a new NumPy array with the the values of `hueL`, `satL` and `valL`. Since `lower` holds the values and not the references, modifying the variables `hueL`, `satL`, `valL` doesn't change the content of `lower`. Play with it (use the debugger, or add prints `lower` and `upper`) to follow when `lower` and `upper` gets changed (and passed to `mask = cv.inRange(color, lower, upper)`).